# volume of a solid when the graph of $f(x)= \sec^2x$

Tags: calculus, volume

Find the volume of the solid of revolution obtained when the graph of $f(x)= \sec^2x$, from $x= -\frac{\pi}{4}$  to  $x= \frac{\pi}{3}$, is rotated about the x-axis. Give your answer to four decimal places.  I think I maybe getting confused as when to changed the limits when using u sub, I have rearranged $(\sec^2x)^2$ to $(\sec^2x)(1+\tan^2x)$ before expanding the brackets and integ.rating

Answer (score 1):

So behind the integral sign you end up with $sec^4x$ and that indeed can be written as $sec^2x(1+tan^2x)$ Now distribute. The first anti derivative is of course just $tanx$ and the second one is a $tan^2x$ multiplied by its own derivative, so anti deriving that gives $\frac{tan^3x}{3}$ Now plug in upper and lower limits. Can you handle it from here?

Comment: as U subistution has been used am i pluging in sqrt 3 and -1 or the orginal limits of −π / 4 and π/3 many thanks

Comment: @confused68  So you got it right?

Comment: sorry still confused as always :/